# Execute iframe via JS function

Tags: html

I have an iframe that I want to execute to take over the window once a javascript function is executed.

This is the whole page iframe:

```
<iframe iframe id="myiFrame" src="http://localhost:3000/" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"> Your browser doesn't support iframes </iframe>
```

The iframe is currently in the body but I can move it to anywhere.

In the javascript I have this function:

```
(value) => {}
```

and would like the iframe to take over the page once the function is executed.

Thanks

Comment: "The iframe is currently in the body but I can move it to anywhere." All markup should be in the body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by `value` in `(value) => {}`.

But here is some code that does this, using classes:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#maximize");
var iframe = document.querySelector("#myiFrame");

function maximizeiFrame() {
  iframe.classList.add("maximized");
}

button.addEventListener("click", maximizeiFrame);
```

```css
#myiFrame {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe.maximized {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<button id="maximize">Maximize iframe</button>

<iframe iframe id="myiFrame" src="http://localhost:3000/"> Your browser doesn't support iframes </iframe>
```